# Python (v2.7) format and print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how to print and format the 1st two rows a list that was read in as a csv file and converted to floating point data (Python v2.7).  Data was then normalized.  I can print out the rows by using a separate print line for each row, but I cant figure out how to only display say the first 3 places after the decimal point.

Depending on what I try I sometimes get error message of :  Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'  -  but the data was converted to floating point - so I don't understand message.

Any tips on how to get the first 2 rows printed and formatted ?  I have tried looking through here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions, but couldn't solve anything.

```
# Normalize columns
normalize_dataset(dataset, minmax)
print ('1st row after normalization', dataset[0])
print ('2nd row after normalization', dataset[1])
#for row in range(2):
 #   print dataset
[format(row, '.3f') for row in dataset]
#print ("Normalization", format(dataset, '.3f'))
```

Attached is the output when I just print two rows with no formatting using a separate line for each row.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZzc5.png)

Updated with code I am using to convert string to float:

```
    for i in range(len(dataset[0])):
        str_to_float(dataset, i) 

    def str_to_float(dataset, column):
        for row in dataset:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.format` method for this.

`print("{0:.2f}".format(dataset))`

Comment: Tried your suggested code and I get and error message - ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'.   Do you have any other suggestions I could try ?

Comment: @very_stuck. Replace the 'f' with 's'.